# Floyd-Warshall Cant find whats wrong

Tags: c#, algorithm, floyd-warshall

I need a new set pair of eyes on this, for some reason its not generating the correct Sequence and Distance matrices the following is my implementation.

This is in C# and DistanceMatrix is a double [,] and SequenceMatrix is a string [,]

these are initiated as follows: http://puu.sh/951Tz/5ef27e3996.png

```
for (int k = 0; k < villageCount; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < villageCount; i++)
            {
                if (k == i)
                    continue;

                for (int j = 0; j < villageCount; j++)
                {
                    if (j == i)
                        continue;

                    if (j == k)
                        continue;

                    if (fw.DistanceMatrix[i, j] >= (fw.DistanceMatrix[i, k] + fw.DistanceMatrix[k, j]))
                    {
                        fw.DistanceMatrix[i, j] = (fw.DistanceMatrix[i, k] + fw.DistanceMatrix[k, j]);
                        fw.SequenceMatrix[i, j] = fw.SequenceMatrix[k, j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

for some reason I'm getting the following output:

```
    [0, 0]  "A" string
    [0, 1]  "B" string
    [0, 2]  "A" string
    [0, 3]  "B" string
    [0, 4]  "D" string
    [1, 0]  "B" string
    [1, 1]  "D" string
    [1, 2]  "D" string
    [1, 3]  "B" string
    [1, 4]  "D" string
    [2, 0]  "B" string
    [2, 1]  "B" string
    [2, 2]  "B" string
    [2, 3]  "B" string
    [2, 4]  "D" string
    [3, 0]  "B" string
    [3, 1]  "B" string
    [3, 2]  "C" string
    [3, 3]  "C" string
    [3, 4]  "D" string
    [4, 0]  "B" string
    [4, 1]  "E" string
    [4, 2]  "D" string
    [4, 3]  "B" string
    [4, 4]  "E" string
```

any pointers would be much appreciated, also if you require more information i'll be F5ing this page :)

distance matrix after init

```
    [0, 0]  0.0                                 double
    [0, 1]  50.0                                    double
    [0, 2]  2.0                                 double
    [0, 3]  10.0                                    double
    [0, 4]  1.7976931348623157E+308 double
    [1, 0]  50.0                                    double
    [1, 1]  0.0                                 double
    [1, 2]  3.0                                 double
    [1, 3]  1.7976931348623157E+308 double
    [1, 4]  1.0                                 double
    [2, 0]  2.0                                 double
    [2, 1]  3.0                                 double
    [2, 2]  0.0                                 double
    [2, 3]  5.0                                 double
    [2, 4]  5.0                                 double
    [3, 0]  10.0                                    double
    [3, 1]  1.7976931348623157E+308 double
    [3, 2]  5.0                                 double
    [3, 3]  0.0                                 double
    [3, 4]  1.7976931348623157E+308 double
    [4, 0]  1.7976931348623157E+308 double
    [4, 1]  1.0                                 double
    [4, 2]  5.0                                 double
    [4, 3]  1.7976931348623157E+308 double
    [4, 4]  0.0                                 double
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: This is from a class mate of mine i gave him screen shots of my code and there are no differences that should effect the algorithm http://puu.sh/94W63/3733d3275f.png also this is the map if you are interested http://puu.sh/954sl/89bd904fda.png if you are interested this is the initiation of the matrix http://puu.sh/954Bu/fc0be21893.png

Comment: You say in your screenshot that you init the values in `DistanceMatrix` to infinity, but do you then set the appropriate elements in it based on the connections in the graph?  The part of the code you posted seems fine

Comment: yes http://puu.sh/9554w/5bbe3027fa.png, currently i'm working out all the iterations by hand to compare the results :/ if you can save me that time :)

Comment: So what does the distance matrix look like after you initialize it?

Comment: See edit for distance matrix after initialization

Comment: In the [pseudo code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd-Warshall_algorithm) for this algorithm it doesn't skip if the different iterators are equal.  Have tried commenting those lines out and seeing what you get?

Comment: that is a performance modification and yes i have tried removing it still same result

Comment: A hint for future reference.  It will usually pay off to get your code working first then worry about performance.  This way you always have a working base line to go back to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed !!! HURRAY

There was no problem to being with !!!!! the nodes where not being Saved

A B C D in the database but rather A D B C, then when reading i was working it out on the index assuming that A is at index 0 B is at index 1 and so on....

Sorry for the waste of time, and thanks a lot !!! for your help !!

Comment: glad you figured that out) saving some attributive information in database may help for such cases

Comment: It is important to note that without Golden Dragon's fix below, your code still wouldn't work... Don't forget to accept his answer

Comment: actually its not implemented with Golden Dragon's fix and it still works, which got me a bit confused as to why, but still a big thanks for everyone's input, also that is how i got to the problem i looked at the data in the database :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe I found the problem.

You are initializing `SequenceMatrix` incorrectly.  Your current have

```
fw.SequenceMatrix[i, j] = map.Villages.ElementAt(i).Name;
```

However, as per the Wikipedia article, it should be

```
fw.SequenceMatrix[i, j] = map.Villages.ElementAt(**j**).Name;
```

Since the sequence matrix shows you the path to take, the values in it should be the destinations, not the starting points.

Looks like there is a mistake in your algorithm, too.  You have

```
fw.SequenceMatrix[i, j] = fw.SequenceMatrix[k, j];
```

But it should be

```
fw.SequenceMatrix[i, j] = fw.SequenceMatrix[**i, k**];
```

Since you have determined that moving from i to k to j is shorter than moving from i to j, you want to set the first step of the new path from i to j to be the same as the first step of the path from i to k.

Comment: So you are still getting identical output to previously?

Comment: No with both of these changes the new output looks like this which is still wrong http://puu.sh/9599j/335a8c0241.png

Comment: You're going to have to debug your code and step though it to see exactly what is going wrong, then.

Comment: HeHe been doing that since 11 this morning

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that inf+inf isn't ok (overflow)? 
Anyway, I think implemetations should look like [this](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/floyd_warshall_algorithm)

```
// d[i][j] == weight of edge (i,j)
// d[i][j] == INF if there is no such edge
// d[i][i] == 0; i = 0, .., n-1

for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            if (d[i][k] < INF && d[k][j] < INF) // i->k, k->j should exist
                d[i][j] = min (d[i][j], d[i][k] + d[k][j]); // INF+INF won't happen
```

Comment: Using min prevents you from maintaining parent-pointers, such as the OP's SequenceMatrix